# If there is a resistor there is a potential drop because the potential energy gets converted to other forms, then how can the current remain constant?

Tags: electric-circuits, energy-conservation, electrical-resistance, potential-energy, dissipation

I am pretty confused about this. If a current flows through a resistor in a series circuit, the resistor opposes the flow of charges. Therefore, the total charge flowing per unit time decreases. How could the current remain constant?

I was thinking about this and I got an idea that when the electrons flow through the resistor, their motion gets opposed and the potential energy gets converted to other forms like heat. So just for that while, the current decreases. Once it crosses the resistor, the charges gain back their original speed due to the potential energy offered to them by the battery.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The alternative is that charges pile up somewhere. The resistor needs voltage to get a certain amount of current through it. That current does not change with time.

Answer (score 0):

No.   The "motion gets opposed" and the "charges gain back their original speed due to potential energy" happen at the same place and at the same time.

Since they happen in the same place, the current never changes.

Comment: If the motion gets opposed, how can the charges move with the same speed? Won't it decrease?

Comment: Not if there is another force of equal magnitude in the opposite directon.   At terminal velocity, air resistance is opposing the motion of a skydiver.   But that doesn't mean they slow down.

Comment: Which means the energy supplied to the individual electrons should increase because they have to do more work? I mean, in spite of there being a resistor, they still manage to flow at the same speed

Comment: Correct.   The electric field in the resistor is greater than the electric field in the wires outside the resistor.

Comment: Alright. I see. So the resistor gives some energy to the current so that it flows at the same speed?

Comment: No, the voltage source is providing energy.   The resistor removes energy.  At steady-state in the circuit, these two are in balance and the current is constant throughout the circuit.

Comment: Okay. So what is this 'potential drop' then?  
For the current to remain constant the potential energy offered by the voltage source should be equal to the energy removed by the resistor otherwise current would decrease.

Comment: "electric field in the resistor is greater than the electric field in the wires outside the resistor."

So at this moment the voltage source gives more energy to the circuit right?

Answer (score 0):

This is no different than water flowing through a restriction like a shower nozzle. The restriction (resistance) combined with the supply pressure (voltage) determine the amount of water flow (current) that will occur. But the flow rate in Liters/s (or current in Coulombs/s which is called Amperes) passing any point in the piping system is the same.

Answer (score 0):

No. charge is conserved, which means every electron entering the resistor comes out the other side. This means the current is constant.

Answer (score 0):

A car traffic analogy may help to augment the other answers.

If you’ve ever driven a car in traffic when there is a lane closure ahead you may have observed you are moving very slowly with many cars (analogous to mobile charge carriers) around you until you reach the length of road with fewer lanes when all of a sudden you and fewer cars around you are going much faster.

It may seem counterintuitive that you move faster when along your route you encounter a section of road that is more restrictive (analogous to encountering higher resistance) until you realize that in order for steady traffic flow along the route the same number of cars have to enter and exit any section of the route (analogous to conservation of charge). That requires the same number of cars per unit time to pass any given cross section of the road (analogous to constant current). The fewer the number of cars able to pass the cross section due to a restriction the faster they need to move (analogous to the drift velocity of charge carriers).

For a detailed discussion of the relationship between mobile charge carriers, current, drift velocity and the diameter and cross section area of a conductor, see

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html

Hope this helps.